# jQuery Offset after CSS Transformation Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on making a mobile web view for zooming and panning an image; using CSS transformations (scale) for zooming and jQuery's "offset()" function for panning.

The problem I am encountering is that if I zoom the image in or out **before** doing any panning, the image jumps to the top left or bottom right corner (respectively) of the view. After the initial jump, the panning and zooming return to working normally. No issues happen if I pan before zooming.

I've narrowed the issue down pretty close, as far as I can tell, to when the offset of the image is being changed during the panning gesture (touchmove). The event listener I am using is similar to:

```
function touchmoveListener(event) {
    // get current touch event coordinates
    var curX = event.X;
    var curY = event.Y;

    // pan image by changing offset
    var curOffset = $("#image").offset();
    var newOffset = {
        left: curOffset.left + (curX - lastX),
         top: curOffset.top  + (curY - lastY)
    };
    $("#image").offset(newOffset);

    // store coordinates for future panning
    lastX = curtX;
    lastY = curY;
}
```

I've console.log'ed the image's original offset, the new computed offset (before assigning), and finally the image's new offset after assignment. When I get the zoom-then-pan issue (zoom in to 2.5x, pan to the left), I get output like this:

```
original offset: {left: -215, top: -100}    // normal original location, okay!
computed offset: {left: -216, top: -100}    // pan 1px to the left, looks good!
assigned offset: {left: -441, top: -325}    // what the...? both off by 225px!
```

I'm really not sure about what the problem is, since I am logging the coordinates of the exact object being passed into the offset() function, and yet the coordinates that are apparently being assigned are completely different. Does anyone have an idea of what's going wrong here? Any input would be appreciated.

Notes:

- I've looked into the jQuery offset() after CSS transformation bug (http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8362) and I am testing using WebKit, but the issue I'm having is apparently with setting the offset, not accessing it.
- lastX and lastY are initialized in response to the touchstart event (before touchmove triggers), so it's not a problem with them

Thanks,

-Brendan

Comment: What's wrong with using CSS transformations for panning?

Comment: @zeroflagL Nothing wrong with CSS panning (it does make the zoom/pan work without bugs), just personal tunnel vision on figuring out why the offset() approach won't work :-P thanks for the input!

Comment: How do you zoom? With a gesture, a control, or a click / touch?

Comment: Gestures (for pinch zooming), and touches (for double click zooming)

Answer (score 0):

[.offset(coordinates)](http://api.jquery.com/offset/#offset2) changes the position of the target element `relative` to the document.

If `#image`'s initial position is something other than `relative`, that may explain the jump in positioning you see when the event listener is first initialized - the image's position is being changed relative to the document, instead of its initial position.